# Get Camera info from already plotted surface plot - plotlyjs

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am dealing with surface plot using plotlyjs.

I made it to show surface plot and change it in real time when I change parameters. What I try to do now is to store camera info of the plot in order to be able to show new plot from the same (previous) view when I update it during parameter change.

I tried to find some answers on the Internet but I found only how to set camera info. I need how to get it from already existing view.

Also, if you have some other ideas how to implement the thing I mentioned I would be very grateful to see them.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

If I want to set the initial camera view on plot I would do something like this:

```
var layout = {
    scene1: {
      domain: {
            x: [0.00,  0.33], 
            y: [0.5, 1]
        },
      camera: {
          center: {
                x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, 
          eye: { 
                x: 2, y: 2, z: 0.1 }, 
           up: {
                x: 0, y: 0, z: 1 }
        },},
```

I want something like myplot.layout.scene.getCamera() if it exists? If yes I would save camera information of the plot when some change happens ( in angular I use watchers for inputs which are important for my data ) and when change and plot reload happen I would like to set camera info to the previous plot camera info.

So If my plot looks like :

http://pokit.org/get/?8a52f4e3aab0cc3abf58de18c6a8c783.jpg

when I change parameters / data (which is not important for my question because it works) I do not want that my new updated plot reload from this view:

http://pokit.org/get/?9bad5bf24d451d7d3a4b62d2c1696d20.jpg

I would like actually to be shown from the same view as previous.

I hope my question is now more clear.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. We cannot help you just with that, we need more details...